# Como faço, em um gradiente de 3 cores, a cor do meio "ficar maior", se destacar?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Eu queria saber se é possível fazer a segunda cor desse gradiente se expandir e se destacar no meio dessas duas cores em uma animação CSS, e se for como eu faço.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, tomato, skyblue, rgb(255, 148, 61));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na função `linear-gradient` você pode informar em qual porcentagem irá iniciar uma determinada cor dentro do gradiente. Por exemplo, você pode configurar que se inicia com a cor `tomato` e chegue ao `skyblue` nos 10% do gradiente; mantenha o `skyblue` até os 90% e depois vá até o `rgb(255, 148, 61)` nos 100%.

Assim, o azul ficará em destaque em cerca de 80% do gradiente, ficando 10% colorido em cada lateral.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, tomato, skyblue 10%, skyblue 90%, rgb(255, 148, 61) 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria, muito obrigado.

Comment: como eu faço isso em animação?

Comment: Aí depende da animação, mas de qualquer forma isso seria discussão para outra pergunta

Comment: A animação que eu queria era que o `skyblue` expandisse

Comment: Então é só criar os frames configurando as porcentagens...